# p5.play counter not working

Tags: animation, counter, p5.js

I'm trying to write a program in which the end screen of the game only shows up after the last animation finishes. I'm using a counter that's implemented after each object is removed (which is only after it finishes its animation), and when that counter gets to zero, it *should* show the end screen. Unfortunately, from what I can tell, the counter statement isn't registering at all. I've inserted a print statement that isn't functioning.

```javascript
var star;
var score;
var counter;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(600,400); 
    score = 0;
    counter = 20;

    for (var s = 0; s < 20; s++) {
        star = createSprite(random(width), random(height));
        star.addAnimation("idle", idleAnim);
        star.addAnimation("explode", explAnim);
        star.changeAnimation("idle");

        star.onMousePressed = function() {
            this.changeAnimation("explode");
            this.animation.looping = false;
            score +=1
             if (this.getAnimationLabel() == "explode" && this.animation.getFrame() == this.animation.getLastFrame()) {
                this.remove();
                counter -= 1;
                print(counter);
            }
        }
    }

}
function draw() {
    if (score == 20 && counter == 0) {
        background(255,222,51)
        textSize(90);
        fill(0)
        text("YOU WIN!",95,225)
    } else {
          drawSprites();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a step back and [debug your program](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). For example, are you sure the `star.onMousePressed()` function is firing? Are you sure the `if` statement is working the way you expected? Are you sure the `player.dir()` function is being called?

It sounds like your `if` statement is not being entered. can you find out the value of everything on that line? Which thing has a different value from what you expected?

Use `console.log()` statements, or use the JavaScript debugger, to answer all of the above. Figure out exactly which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected, and then isolate that problem in a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck.